# Shopping-cart script as nearly as Payvment

Tags: php

I would like to know if there are any shopping cart scripts which looks as nearly as Payvment

Payvment on facebook https://apps.facebook.com/payvment/

I want to know if the features it uses (mostly AJAX) can be accomplished via shopping cart script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following open source shopping carts

- osCommerce
- Zen Cart
- Mejento

and build your own shopping cart